# Align JPanel to right while still making the JPanel expandable using MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, miglayout

How to align JPanel to the right while at the same time making the JPanel expandable (shrink and expand) using MigLayout?

I am trying to display a inner JPanel within another outer JPanel and want to make the inner JPanel expandable. The inner JPanel has a component JPanel (another JPanel with buttons) on it. I also want the component JPanel to aligh right. I have used the following code but it does not work; the component JPanel is displayed to the left.

```
JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("debug, wrap, ins 0, fillx"));
innerPanel.setFocusable(false);        
innerPanel.add(componentPanel, "grow, right");
outerPanel.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This might even be a bug (who knows).

Comment: Thanks to @jason-s I found the right answer. Thanks Jason :-)